# If $f^{-1}$(a) $\in$ $\chi$ for all a $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ then f is a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

$f$ : $X$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$ is a function on a measurable space ($X$, $\chi$).

I would like to show that this statement is $false$:

If $f^{-1}$(a) $\in$ $\chi$ for all a $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ then f is a measurable function

---

I know that if $f$ is a measurable function then $f^{−1}$(a) ∈ $\chi$ for all a $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$

but I am having trouble showing the converse is false.

I can see that $f^{-1}$(B) $\in$ $\chi$, B being a Borel subset, but just a $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$?

any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest counterexample is probably to set $X = [0,1]$ with the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, $V \subset X$ a non-measurable set, and $f(x) := x + 1_V(x)$.  Then $f$ is injective so $f^{-1}(a)$ is a singleton for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and hence measurable, but $f$ is clearly not measurable (if it were, then $f(x) - x$ would also be, but $f(x)-x = 1_V$ which was chosen to be non-measurable).

Answer (score 0):

The sigma algebra generated by $\{a| a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is the countable-cocountable sigma algebra on the real line, i.e. $\{A\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|$either $A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable$\}$, which is a sub-sigma algebra of the Borel sigma algebra.

In this case, a simple counterexample is any interval, say $[0,1]$, since both $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^c$ are uncountable. So, even if $f^{-1}(a)\in\chi, \forall a\in \mathbb{R}$, there is no guarantee that $f^{-1}([0,1])\in\chi$.